# Did 12th century French nobles really sleep in the great hall of the castle?

Tags: middle-ages, europe, france, everyday-life, nobility

I've been on so many sites and each one seems to tell a different story. Some say that nobles had their own bedrooms (evidenced by the fact that castles had bedrooms) but I have also seen people say that lords kept their beds in the Great Hall which they shared with the servants. That seems strange to me because a) where do you keep the bed during the day while using the hall for other activities and b) I cannot imagine them being fine with sharing their sleeping quarters with servants. Same thing with guests. No one seems to be able to tell me where the guests slept when they slept over. Could someone please help me clear this out?

Comment: Could you bring some examples of where you've read about this and which sites tell the story? It is likely both versions are true on different levels (you wouldn't expect the king and a lowly count to behave similarly given they'd have different financial abilities to provide for themselves).

Comment: The only descriptions I'm seeing along these lines are fictional.

Comment: Castles often took years, or even on occasion decades, to be completed. That which was common early on need not have been common later in the period, or even simply later in the history of a particular estate.

Comment: Why is this difficult to imagine?

Comment: I believe the "Great Hall" was more of a Germanic thing.

Comment: My only source on this is Shadiversity on Youtube so take this with a grain of salt, but castles came in all kinds of sizes, and the same goes for noble titles. Many early castles only had two or three rooms and, well, everybody needed a place to sleep. And on the same note, not every low-level noble had legions of servants.

Comment: Though this could use some additional detail, I think a good answer to this could help solve many misconceptions about castles. As such, I don't agree with the closure process as it stands. I can't provide an answer right now, but if this is still open late tomorrow, I will try.